# Which code is updating my List Items

Tags: 2010

I've a very peculiar problem. I've a task list which is getting modified by "System Account" daily. Tasks are getting into Pending status from Completed or Draft.

Timing is almost the same: 1:00AM UTC daily; Around 3000 items out of 6000 are getting updated.

Is there anyway to know which CODE is doing that?

I've checked the timer jobs that ran during that time but found nothing, I also checked there is no PowerShell being scheduled.

No LOG seems to point to a solution name!

Can anybody give me some thinking points to find the culprit webpart, event receiver, Timer Job.

Comment: Configure diagnostic logging to Verbose level. Then monitor the ULS log around the daily update time.

Comment: It is on verbose

Comment: Are all tasks in the list affected? Are they all edited at the same exact time? Is it occurring by night, always at the same time, or is it "random"?

Comment: Check whether retention policy is enabled on particular list or content type.

Comment: @Evariste Same time daily, around 2000 items affected

Comment: Retention policy defined is set to NO